# Recovering a filesystem with a large amount of inode checksum errors - ext4 64 bit on debian 11

Tags: linux, ext4, file-metadata

The situation is as follows: I have a (very old) filesystem - it was created in 2006.
It started off as ext2, got migrated to ext3, then to ext4, then to ext4 with 64bit.
I recently enabled metadata_csum for it and have not had issues with it that I could tell - even the oldest data, when sampled, seemed to be correctly retrievable.
routine fsck on the filesystem has been disabled since when it was created.
After a slight OOPS on the underlying mdraid due to an HBA cable leaping for freedom, I reassembled the FS and I am presently fscking it before mounting it.
One potential issue is that mdraid reassembly had a slight further OOPS and the volume was assigned metadata 1.2 before being reassigned the (correct and previous) metadata 0.90.
As a result, ~300 bytes 4096 bytes from the beginning of each underlying partition were overwritten. A total of 12 blocks, let's say, one per disk.
Keeping that in mind, I am fscking the fs : of course the first superblock got zapped, but fsck correctly went to a backup superblock and is happily churning away. There don't seem to be any errors except a very large number of `Inode nnnnn passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix? no`.
By very large number I mean almost 10^6, on a fs with 2.6*10^9 inodes.
Given that the only other errors are less than 20 `Inode nnnn contains garbage. Clear? no`is it possible that what is happening is that the metadata for the 'old' inodes, that is to say those that were NOT written to after the enabling of the feature, is simply incorrect?
There was a lot of discussion about this in 2010-2013, then it sort of vanished.
If this is the case, would I be best serve by removing the feature, fscking to fix the other errors, then adding it back?
This is a 40TB volume and because reasons (TM) the last backup is ~ 18 months old.

For reference, the system is presently running Debian 11 with current updates, amd64.

Comment: have you tried the linux-ext4 mailing lists?  I know at least the btrfs mailing list has been very welcoming to discuss potential corruption issues.  I would also recommend to back up the block device somehow (40TB is a lot of space to find somewhere) before trying fsck again, so at least you can go back and try something different.

Comment: I haven't yet - that is my next planned step.
I know Theodore Ts'o still posts there and back when I had concerns about converting to ext4 ~ four years ago he took the time to deal with my concerns. 
I agree about backing up the drives - I was going to image the single drives of the mdraid onto a separate volume as soon as more drives arrive and before doing any writing, all operations are RO at the present time, save for that stupid assembly mistake.

Comment: An alternative to backing up the pv's, is doing a bunch of dd on the lv device with different skips, that way you can chunk it any way you want, without intermixing lvm metadata.

Comment: True, but if I dd the actual mdraid partitions I can play around with combinations as well, just in case THAT somehow ended up out of order. Of course, that would require 80TB of space...

Comment: So far no luck on linux-ext4. Trying on linux-raid.

Comment: And I got it to work.
Thanks to generous help by Phil T at linux-raid, I was able to reconstruct the raid, mount it read only, overlay it, fsck the first time - which evidently only fixed the block group descriptors and complained about being unable to set the superblock flags, then exited.
At that point, however, mount -o ro was successful *and* the data appears to be intact. Thus, I will be copying the contents to another array and keeping this as a backup.
Mission accomplished, in any case.
For future reference, if anything like this happens, overlay your member devices *right away*.

Comment: cool.  I didn't even think about that.  the overlay was an lvm snapshot?  I'll have to remember that trick.

Comment: Well, technically it was a device mapper snapshot, which is also used by lvm, yes.
I found that little trick by going back to the Linux RAID Wiki, which has grown a lot in the past few years and now includes several tricks for when you're desperate. That plus Phil's help got me through.
There are a few remaining questions, which I kind of sideskirted, like 'is this going to be repeatable?' - which I tried to address by imaging the journal device. I should have put an overlay over that as well, but it would have been tricky to fsck with a different journal device.